# How to pass 2 features to LSTM , one of them is one-hot-encoded with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, rnn

I have a very simple LSTM model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(seq_length, X_train.shape[2]) , return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(y_cat_train.shape[2], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_cat_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=2)
```

The input `X_train` has 2 feature , one is categorical (values 1-4) and the other is numeric (values 1-100). There are 4 classes in `y_test` that I one-hot-encoded with keras's `to_categorical` .

1. Should I encode the categorical input feature as well ? If I do , how can I pass it along with the other feature ? (e.g. now a timestep looks like this for example: `[1,44]`)
2. Later , I would like to take make a sampling , meaning I need to take the predicted `y_hat<t-1>` and pass it as `x<t>` . I will have to pass the second numeric feature (1-100) along with it. How can it be done ?

EDIT : note that I do not want my numeric feature to become categorical since there is importance to the values (meaning 2<10<90 etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Yes, it is a common practice to encode the categorical feature by one-hot encoding, for example, encode `[1,44]` as `[1,0,0,0,44]`, encode `[2,44]` as `[0,1,0,0,44]`, etc.

(2) Same as (1), just concatenate the one-hot encoded categorical feature and the numerical feature(s).

Comment: So it will be treated as one feature ? The categorical part is actually`y<t-1>` so `X<t> = [y<t-1>,feature2]`  - won't concatenating lose some of the importance of one of the features ?